# What does ... means? Does it have a meaning?

Tags: python

I sometimes see and do not understand the meaning of `...` . Three periods.
Below is the example of which I do not understand:

```
>>> t = 12345, 54321, 'hello!'
>>> t[0]
12345
>>> t
(12345, 54321, 'hello!')
>>> # Tuples may be nested:
... u = t, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
>>> u
((12345, 54321, 'hello!'), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

What are these three periods doing in front of `u`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just a visual aid of the IDE you are using to show you are continuing the same line / block.

Another example:

```
>>> x = 1 + (
... 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

In your case, it's mostly to show that you're continuing the same block of code. However, in Python there is an `Ellipsis` object mostly used for `numpy` arrays, but in Python3.x, it's also usable as `...`, so typing that in a Python3.x interpreter will return `Ellipsis`...

*As line/block continuation*:

```
>>> if 3 > 2:
...    print 'yes' # indicates we're inside another block or continuing a statement
```

*As Ellipsis (in Python 3.x)*:

```
Python 3.3.0 (default, Sep 29 2012, 17:14:58) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ...
Ellipsis
```